# ActionBar refresh button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I've added on my ActionBar a Refresh button, but the thing is that I have this refresh button always on my ActionBar. I've heared that I have to create an

Here's where I add the icon :

```
 <item android:id="@+id/ofertasRefresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

And then I've added this amount of code on my Activity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.optionsMenu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); //ERROR<-----------
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // in Fragment cannot be applied <------------
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.airport_menuRefresh:

            // Complete with your code
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void setRefreshActionButtonState(final boolean refreshing) {
    if (optionsMenu != null) {
        final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu
                .findItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh);
        if (refreshItem != null) {
            if (refreshing) {
                refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
            } else {
                refreshItem.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On `getMenuInflater()` says that "Cannont resolve the method" and then in "appears" that "in Fragment cannot be applied"...

EDITED*

I thought that my problem was focused on MyActivity.java then I pasted the code that I have of `OnCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`

MyActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you are using supportMenuInflater on import. And you shouldn't return super, returning true is enough.

Comment: I replaced it, and what about the "getMenuInflater"...?

Comment: where you are calling `getMenuInflater` ? from Fragment?

Comment: What do you mean? Let's see, I've got a Drawer Navigation okay? Then I want that when I press a specific object on my navigation drawer appears a refresh icon... Do you understand what I'm trying to explain?

Comment: Are you using standart android.app.Activity or actionbarShelockActivity?

Comment: Why don't you simply use this --> `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {` 
  `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`
  `menu.findItem(R.id.Refresh).setVisible(true);`
 `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling from an Activity use

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //this.optionsMenu = menu;
    //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); //ERROR<-----------
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // in Fragment cannot be applied <------------
    return true;
}
```

to inflate the menu in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

And, as the comments say just return `true` from the same method.

If calling from a fragment the method will look slightly different:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
        Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that I can do this? `MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`, it doesn't work.. it still saying that cannot resolve method

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the whole method to make things clearer. Your "bad" lines are hashed out.

Comment: Well.. now it doesn't say nothing wrong, but it still showing on every activity, I just want to show it in one activity, not in ActionBar permanently.

Comment: If you implemented the first option from within a class in which you extend Activity, then it would only show for that activity. But it sounds like you have multiple fragments within a main activity -- but I don't know that for a fact because I can't see more of your code. If that's the case use the second option. It will add additional menu items for that fragment.

Comment: I've tried your first option but it still saying that can't implement method, if you want to see more code of my App let me know and i'll post it.

Comment: If in doubt which to use, and if using Eclipse as your IDE, then click Source>Override/Implment Methods . . . and find the appropriate onCreateOptions menu. This will create a new method from scratch and you can then edit it to include the correct menu resource. (Delete or comment out your old method after all this, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
       switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {
         case R.id.search:  // it is going to refer the search id name in main.xml

         //add your code here

            return true;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```

**main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"  --> add a icon in drawable that will display in the top of the action bar.
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

With the help of above code,you will get one menu item in top of the action bar.Then whatever the code you add inside the `case R.id.search:` that will perform the function.